# File extension Python

Tags: python

If a directory contains both '.m' and '.xml' files I want the script to find them both (which it won't do at the moment, instead it goes to the 'else' statement). The given argument should look for all files in a directory.

```
python script.py --dir C:\\path\\path\\*.* #This should take all files (doesn't matter what type ex 'm', 'xml' 'txt' etc.).
```

If the user only wants xml files he writes *.xml and vice versa for '.m' files. Do note if the user only wants 'XML' or 'm' files the script will find it

```
def main(argv):
    args = argumentParser(argv)
    if args.dirname.endswith('.m'):
        overrideM(args)
    elif args.dirname.endswith('.xml'):
        xmlOverride(args)
    elif args.dirname.endswith(('.m', '.xml')): #Can I do like this?
        #Here I want to run both of my function.
        overrideM()
        xmlOverride()
    else:
        print "Error can't find files"
```

My 'm' function(small part of it)

```
def overrideM(args):
    for fileName in glob.glob(args.dirname):
        print fileName
        with open(fileName, 'r') as searchFile:
            my_files_content = searchFile.read()
        #...rest of my code
```

My 'XML' function (small part of it)

```
def xmlOverride(args):
    for fileName in glob.glob(args.dirname):
        print fileName
        with open(fileName, 'r') as searchFile:
            my_files_content = searchFile.read()
        #...rest of my code
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Well it won't, instead it gives me "Error can't find files"

Comment: Are you sure argv or args contains anything?

Comment: `args.dirname.endswith(('.m', '.xml'))` checks either file ends with `xml` or `m`. Seems you have checked it already separately. What for you are checking again?

Comment: Actually to run both it won't work, what is args? How could it end with two different extensions?

Comment: log somewhere args `print(args)` please, to make it clear

Comment: @Rudziankoŭ hmm by doing "print args" it gives me C:\path\path\*.* . So maybe the code don't understand that i want it to check all files?

Comment: @gants, your logic could not possibly work, if args is a string which it has to be or your code would error then it cannot possibly have two different extensions, if you want to give the user the options for multiple extensions then you would need to get a tuple of extensions and iterate over that, how could a string  end in .m and .xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`elif args.dirname.endswith(('.m', '.xml'))` could not possibly work, if args is a string which it has to be or your code would error then it cannot possibly have two different extensions, you would need to get a tuple of extensions if a user wanted to select both, something like:

```
def main(argv):
    # make argumentParser return a tuple
    args = argumentParser(argv)
    if sorted(args) == ('.m', '.xml'):
        overrideM()
        xmlOverride()
```

A better option is to use a generic function that takes a file extension and just iterate of the args passing in the extension:

```
def main(argv):
    args = argumentParser(argv)
    for ext in args:
        generic_search(ext)
```

There is no way you can use `args.dirname.endswith(('.m', '.xml'))` on a string if you are trying to match both, the string simply cannot end in both `.m` and `.xml`. I would also take the paths as one arg and the extensions to search for as separate args then you can glob each one individually or use *str.endswith* with multiple extensions using os.listdir to list the files.

The basic idea would be something like:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path")
parser.add_argument('ext', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
path = args.path
exts = args.ext

# what your glob is doing
for f in os.listdir(path):
    if f.endswith(tuple(exts)):
        with open(os.path.join(path, f)) as fle:
            print(fle.name)
            # do whatever
```

If you are allowing the user to search for multiple files then unless you are doing something very specific in each function it is better to use endswith and do one pass over the directory.

You can also combine it with glob if you also want to search all the subdirectories as well as path:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os
from glob import iglob

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path")
parser.add_argument('ext', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
path = args.path
exts = args.ext

for f in chain.from_iterable([iglob(path+"/*"), iglob(path+"/**/*")]):
    if f.endswith(tuple(exts)):
        with open(os.path.join(path, f)) as fle:
            print(fle.name)
```

Again it will work for multiple file extensions do one pass over the directories. glob is good for single matches or maybe a couple but if you have multiple extensions then it makes a lot more sense to use listdir and filer with endswith.

If you really want to use different logic for each extension you can pull the extension and use a dict to call the appropriate function mapping extension name to the function:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import os
from glob import iglob

def xml(f):
    print(f)

def m(f):
    print(f)

def text(f):
   print(f)

mapped = {"m":m, "xml":xml, "text":text}

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("path")
parser.add_argument('ext', nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()
path = args.path
exts = args.ext


for f in chain.from_iterable([iglob(path + "/*"), iglob(path + "/**/*")]):
    ext = f.rsplit(".", 1)
    if len(ext) == 2 and ext[1] in mapped:
        mapped[ext[1]](f)
```

The dict lookup is *O(1)* so apart from being concise it is also very efficient.

Sample output:

```
 $ python 3_payg.py  /home/padraic  .xml 
/home/padraic/sitemap.xml
/home/padraic/yacy/build.xml
/home/padraic/graphviz-master/graphviz.appdata.xml
```

Comment: Right now there will only be max 3 extension. So I assume glob would be a smart choice here?

I am also trying out yours and the other suggestions, hopefully I manage to fix it :)

Comment: @gants, well you can do three passes with glob or one with the os.listdir logic, really glob is ideal for one extension otherwise you are checking every file * number of extensions regardless, using str.endswidth you do one pass albeit potentially the same amount of checks if you get no matches which is unlikely though. The listdir logic should be the fastest way to do it when you have multiple extensions.

Answer (score 0):

1) I don't have big friendship with `MS Windows` but anyway it similar to `UNIX`, you sould expose to your command prompt that you want the product of command not just mere command. In UNIX it will looks:

```
 python script.py $(ls home/)
```

2) The second problem is you args will be a string e.g: `"file.xml, file.m, file.txt"` and e.g. this string ends with `.txt`. So this is a point where you will miss your files with needed extension.

To make it work you have to iterate over list of files.

```
files = args.split(",")
for file in files:
     main(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

At least in Bash, `*` wildcards are expanded by the *shell*, not be the process being run. `sys.argv` would contain a lot of files. On Windows it might be different.

You would have a better control by passing the directory to search in like this (I'm skipping argparse, but you should keep using it).

```
myscript.py c:\a\directory
```

and using [glob or iglob](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) to retreive the files.

```
import sys
import glob
import os
import itertools

# retreive your directory to expore, from the arguments
# just for the example, better use argparse
dir = sys.argv[1]

# At this point, you might wish to use os.path.abspath & friends
# to have a normalized directory, and check its existence with
# os.path.exists.

# The patterns to search for:
patterns = "*.xml", "*.m"

# a generator expression yielding things like 
# "c:\\my\\dir\\*.xml" and "c:\\my\\dir\\*.m"
joint_patterns  = (os.path.join(dir, pt) for pt in patterns)

# Glob the joint patterns into a super-generator:
files = itertools.chain.from_iterable( glob.iglob(pt) for pt in joint_patterns )

# Show the result. the '*' is there to evaluate the super generator
# or else it'd print something like 
# "<itertools.chain object at 0x7fd92ac9efd0>"
print(*files)
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you won't benefit from your shell's fancy facilities regarding wildcards.

## Edit

You don't need to create the super generator with `chain` in your case. You just retreive the glob iterator for each pattern:

```
import sys
import glob
import os
import itertools

# retreive your directory to expore, from the arguments
# just for the example, better use argparse
dir = sys.argv[1]
# The patterns to search for:
patterns = "*.xml", "*.m"

# a LIST  holding things like 
# "c:\\my\\dir\\*.xml" and "c:\\my\\dir\\*.m"
joint_patterns = [os.path.join(dir, pt) for pt in patterns]

# Glob iterators.
globs = [glob.iglob(pt) for pt in joint_patterns]

for xml_file_path in globs[0]:
    do_xml_stuff(xml_file_path)

for m_file_path in globs[1]:
    do_m_stuff(m_file_path)
```